# Remove Minecraft formatting codes from a String

Tags: java

I obtain strings that contain chat messages, and they sometimes have formatting codes imbedded in them. A formatting code is a `§` followed by a character, and this character then defines how the code will affect the following text. Colour codes can occur at the very end of the String, a common case of a message would be:

`"§r§aThis is a message.§r§bAnd this is blue...§r"`

Currently I'm using this method, which simply iterates over the String and skips another character when it encounters a `§`. Is this a good solution, and how can I further improve it?

```java
private String cleanFormattingCodes(String message) {
    StringBuilder newMessage = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
      char c = message.charAt(i);
      if (c == '§') {
        i++;
        continue;
      }

      newMessage.append(c);
    }
    return newMessage.toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite straightforward code, no bells or whistles. Your implementation removes a lone § if it is at the end of the string (e.g. "this gets removed §"). Is it supposed to do that? I would rename `newMessage` to `cleanMessage` as the message is not new, just a cleaned one. And change the unmoddified variables to final (`final StringBuilder cleanMessage` and `final char c`).

That ends my code review. Now for the improvements.

The whole method can be replaced with a short [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

```
return message.replaceAll("§.", "");
```

It is also possible to make a regex that matches "§ + letter" instead of "§ + any char" as both our implementations now do.

Comment: I think you have an error: the regular expression should be `§.`.

Comment: @RoToRa Thanks, my regex game is getting rusty...

Answer (score 3):

I have only three small points:

1. The formatting/indentation isn't quite ok, but that may be just a copy and past error.
2. Since you know the (maximum) length of the final string, you could initialize the `StringBuilder` with a capacity. That has the advantage, that the `StringBuilder` won't need to allocate new memory inbetween:

```
StringBuilder newMessage = new StringBuilder(message.length());
```

3. I feel that the use of `continue` makes the loop a bit awkward to read. Since the rest of the loop body is just one line, I think a simple `else` would be better: (And a small comment wouldn't out of place.)

```
if (c == '§') {
  // Skip the following character
  i++;
} else {
  newMessage.append(c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, this code breaks the rule of "least surprise" :

```
for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
  char c = message.charAt(i);
  if (c == '§') {
    i++;
    continue;
  }

  newMessage.append(c);
}
```

The loop variable `i` is incremented in the loop control and in the body of the loop. That goes against my expectations of the behaviour of a `for` loop.

If your code is going to work this way, my preference would be for the loop to be a `while` loop, with the index explicitly managed in the different code paths - like this (untested code).

```
int i = 0;
while (i < message.length()) {
  char c = message.charAt(i);
  if (c == '§') {
    i += 2; // skip the 2-character formatting code
  } else {
    newMessage.append(c);
    i += 1 // move on to the next character.
  }
}
```

I've used "i += *n*" in both cases for symmetry.

As Torben has pointed out, you could just use String.replaceAll(*regex*)...

Torben's regex solution, like your manual copying, assumes that there is never any reason for your flag character to appear in the string other than as part of a formatting code. Can you confidently assert that that is the case? If, for example, the flag was allowed to appear as text, preceded perhaps by a quote character such as '\' your code breaks:

```
"I've learned how to remove \§ from strings"
```

would become

```
"I've learned how to remove \from strings"
```

If this sort of thing is possible, your code needs to be more subtle. I'd probably use a State Machine, but that's just a little foible of mine...